# Card Presenter expands in Android 4.4 when selected

Tags: android, android-tv

This is the code for `cardpresenter.java` here the `card_width` and `card_height` is specified but it does not follows in Android Kitkat. How to make `CardView` compatibility with Android 4.4.3?

```
package com.example.sahilbhatoa.iitv;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ImageCardView;
import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.Presenter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

/*
 * A CardPresenter is used to generate Views and bind Objects to them on demand.
 * It contains an Image CardView
 */
public class CardPresenter extends Presenter {
    private static final String TAG = "CardPresenter";

    private static final int CARD_WIDTH = 313;
    private static final int CARD_HEIGHT = 176;
    private static int sSelectedBackgroundColor;
    private static int sDefaultBackgroundColor;
    private Drawable mDefaultCardImage;

    private static void updateCardBackgroundColor(ImageCardView view, boolean selected) {
        int color = selected ? sSelectedBackgroundColor : sDefaultBackgroundColor;
        // Both background colors should be set because the view's background is temporarily visible
        // during animations.

        view.setBackgroundColor(color);
        view.findViewById(R.id.info_field).setBackgroundColor(color);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder");

        sDefaultBackgroundColor = parent.getResources().getColor(R.color.default_background);
        sSelectedBackgroundColor = parent.getResources().getColor(R.color.selected_background);
        mDefaultCardImage = parent.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.movie);

        ImageCardView cardView = new ImageCardView(parent.getContext())

        {
            @Override
            public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
                updateCardBackgroundColor(this, selected);
                super.setSelected(selected);
            }
        };

        cardView.setFocusable(true);
        cardView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        updateCardBackgroundColor(cardView, false);
        return new ViewHolder(cardView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Object item) {

        ImageCardView cardView = (ImageCardView) viewHolder.view;
        cardView.setMainImageDimensions(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
        if (item instanceof Movie)
        {
            Movie movie = (Movie) item;
            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder");
            if (movie.getCardImageUrl() != null) {
                cardView.setTitleText(movie.getTitle());
                cardView.setContentText(movie.getCategory());
                cardView.setMainImageDimensions(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
                Glide.with(viewHolder.view.getContext())
                        .load(movie.getCardImageUrl())
                        .centerCrop()
                        .error(mDefaultCardImage)
                        .into(cardView.getMainImageView());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cardView.setTitleText(item.toString());
            cardView.setMainImageDimensions(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);

            if (item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("categories"))
                Glide.with(viewHolder.view.getContext())
                    .load(R.drawable.categories)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .error(mDefaultCardImage)
                    .into(cardView.getMainImageView());
            else if (item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Account Summary"))
                Glide.with(viewHolder.view.getContext())
                        .load(R.drawable.account_summary)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .error(mDefaultCardImage)
                        .into(cardView.getMainImageView());
            else if (item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Video On Demand"))
                Glide.with(viewHolder.view.getContext())
                        .load(R.drawable.videoondemand)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .error(mDefaultCardImage)
                        .into(cardView.getMainImageView());
            else if (item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Customer Support"))
                Glide.with(viewHolder.view.getContext())
                        .load(R.drawable.customer_support)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .error(mDefaultCardImage)
                        .into(cardView.getMainImageView());
            else if (item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Favorites"))
                Glide.with(viewHolder.view.getContext())
                        .load(R.drawable.favourites)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .error(mDefaultCardImage)
                        .into(cardView.getMainImageView());

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onUnbindViewHolder(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onUnbindViewHolder");
        ImageCardView cardView = (ImageCardView) viewHolder.view;
        // Remove references to images so that the garbage collector can free up memory
        cardView.setBadgeImage(null);
        cardView.setMainImage(null);
    }
}
```

[In this the Card view works perfectly with same code just OS is android 5.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU3Uh.png)

[Card View expands to full screen. Here the OS is Android 4.4.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCezu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a pending [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197110) for this. Possible that all API before API 21 may have this issue. You may want to follow this to be updated about the said issue. For the meanwhile, try using Android version API 21 and above. Hope this helps